# hmac.New(h func() hash.Hash, key []byte) hash.Hash equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, go, hash, hmac

Almost I got stuck in the js implementation of go lang [hmac.New](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/hmac#:%7E:text=func%20New%20%28h%20func%20%28%29%20hash.%20Hash%2C%20key,a%20new%20Hash%20every%20time%20it%20is%20called.) for several days. However, no success. I used `crypto`,`crypto-js` and `stablelib` modules for implementation. The problem is that in go lang version, `hmac` instance can be created by `hmac` instance. For example (**the code block is correct and tested**):

```
hmacf := hmac.New(func() hash.Hash {
    return hmac.New(func() hash.Hash {
        return hmac.New(func() hash.Hash {
            return hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(SALT))
        }, []byte(path[0]))
    }, []byte(path[1]))
}, []byte(path[2]))
```

Actually, I don't know how does it work! because in all javascript related modules, You can't create `hmac` from `hmac`, and they accept an `string` value that determines hashing algorithm.

maybe it's better to ask how to create `hmac` from `hmac` in javascript.

### What is the solution?

When the output of go version is the same with the output of your implementation; Your solution is correct.

Comment: Not a Go expert, but the code doesn't seem to work: https://go.dev/play/p/3ca-zIt4Wwx. Can you post executable code and test data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the specification ([RFC 2104](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2104)), an HMAC uses a digest function internally, e.g. SHA256.

However, your implementation applies (actually non-compliant) HMACs that internally use another HMAC instead of a digest, where only the lowest level HMAC uses a regular digest internally. In this way, a nested structure is created.

Based on the specification of a regular HMAC (with a digest), this can be extended to the HMAC with an HMAC (instead of a digest) as used in the Go code:

`HMAC(K XOR opad, HMAC(K XOR ipad, text))` s. [RFC2104, sec 2. Definition of HMAC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2104#section-2)

---

Because of the difference from the specification, it will probably not be so easy to find a JavaScript library that supports something like this out of the box.
Although most libraries of course support an HMAC, but only allow the specification of a digest (and not of an HMAC), e.g. [`crypto.createHmac()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatehmacalgorithm-key-options) of the crypto module of NodeJS, see also the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76630797/9014097). I don't think this approach can be used to implement the logic from the Go code.

If the approach of the other answer doesn't work and you can't find another JavaScript library with the needed functionality, you can implement the logic in JavaScript yourself, because the specification of the HMAC is relatively simple (s. above).

---

The following code is a sample implementation with the crypto module of NodeJS:

```js
var crypto = require('crypto')

const digest = 'sha256'
const blockSize = 64 // block size of the digest

// define input parameter
var salt = Buffer.from('salt')
var path = [ Buffer.from('alfa'), Buffer.from('beta'), Buffer.from('gamma') ]
var data = Buffer.from('data')

// calculate HMAC
var hmac = hmac(data, salt, path)
console.log(hmac.toString('hex'))

function hmac(data, salt, path) {
    
    // create keyList
    var keyList = []
    keyList.push(salt)
    keyList = keyList.concat(path)

    // determine HMAC recursively
    var result = hmac_rec(data, keyList)
    return result
}

function hmac_rec(data, keyList) {

    // adjust key (according to HMAC specification)
    var key = keyList.pop()
    if (key.length > blockSize) {        
        k = Buffer.allocUnsafe(blockSize).fill('\x00');
        if (keyList.length > 0) {
            hmac_rec(key, [...keyList]).copy(k)
        } else {
            getHash(key).copy(k)
        }
    } else if (key.length < blockSize) {
        k = Buffer.allocUnsafe(blockSize).fill('\x00');
        key.copy(k)
    } else {
        k = key
    }

    // create 'key xor ipad' and 'key xor opad' (according to HMAC specification)  
    var ik = Buffer.allocUnsafe(blockSize)
    var ok = Buffer.allocUnsafe(blockSize)
    k.copy(ik)
    k.copy(ok)
    for (var i = 0; i < ik.length; i++) {
        ik[i] = 0x36 ^ ik[i] 
        ok[i] = 0x5c ^ ok[i]
    }

    // calculate HMAC
    if (keyList.length > 0) {
        var innerHMac = hmac_rec(Buffer.concat([ ik, data ]), [...keyList]) 
        var outerHMac = hmac_rec(Buffer.concat([ ok, innerHMac ]), [...keyList])
    } else {
        var innerHMac = getHash(Buffer.concat([ik, data]))
        var outerHMac = getHash(Buffer.concat([ok, innerHMac]))
    }
  
    return outerHMac 
}

// calculate SHA256 hash
function getHash(data){
    var hash = crypto.createHash(digest);
    hash.update(data)
    return hash.digest()
}
```

with the result:

```
2e631dcb4289f8256861a833ed985fa945cd714ebe7c3bd4ed4b4072b107b073
```

---

Test:

The following Go code produces the same result:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "hash"
)

func main() {
    SALT := "salt"
    path := []string{"alfa", "beta", "gamma"}
    hmacf := hmac.New(func() hash.Hash {
        return hmac.New(func() hash.Hash {
            return hmac.New(func() hash.Hash {
                return hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(SALT))
            }, []byte(path[0]))
        }, []byte(path[1]))
    }, []byte(path[2]))
    hmacf.Write([]byte("data"))
    result := hmacf.Sum(nil)
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(result)) // 2e631dcb4289f8256861a833ed985fa945cd714ebe7c3bd4ed4b4072b107b073
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76836631/9014097), the following is a more compact/efficient implementation for `hmac_rec()` that uses the regular HMac for the last iteration step (which also makes `getHash()` obsolete):

```js
function hmac_rec(data, keyList) {
    var key = keyList.pop()
    if (keyList.length > 0) {
        
        // adjust key (according to HMAC specification)
        if (key.length > blockSize) {        
            k = Buffer.allocUnsafe(blockSize).fill('\x00');
            hmac_rec(key, [...keyList]).copy(k)
        } else if (key.length < blockSize) {
            k = Buffer.allocUnsafe(blockSize).fill('\x00');
            key.copy(k)
        } else {
            k = key
        }
    
        // create 'key xor ipad' and 'key xor opad' (according to HMAC specification)  
        var ik = Buffer.allocUnsafe(blockSize)
        var ok = Buffer.allocUnsafe(blockSize)
        k.copy(ik)
        k.copy(ok)
        for (var i = 0; i < ik.length; i++) {
            ik[i] = 0x36 ^ ik[i] 
            ok[i] = 0x5c ^ ok[i]
        }

        // calculate HMAC
        var innerHMac = hmac_rec(Buffer.concat([ ik, data ]), [...keyList]) 
        var outerHMac = hmac_rec(Buffer.concat([ ok, innerHMac ]), [...keyList])
    } else {
        var outerHMac = crypto.createHmac(digest, key).update(data).digest();
    }  
    return outerHMac 
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much, I am excited to test it to see the result. if it worked I would recommend you put it in an npm public repository.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this?

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const encoding = 'hex';
const SALT = 'your_salt_value';
const path = ['path1', 'path2', 'path3'];

const hmacf = crypto.createHmac('sha256', SALT)
    .update(path[0])
    .digest(encoding);
const hmacf2 = crypto.createHmac('sha256', hmacf)
    .update(path[1])
    .digest(encoding);
const hmacf3 = crypto.createHmac('sha256', hmacf2)
    .update(path[2])
    .digest(encoding);
        
console.log(hmacf3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: I don't quite understand what result you want. In any case, I already suggested that `WebAssembly` or something else could be used. I don't recommend getting hung up on the perfect solution to this problem, but it's your choice.

Comment: There are limitations to using `WebAssembly` on different execution envs. For the desired result, you can compare the go version output with js implemented output